# If array includes a cetain key then delete entire object using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I am getting back a 2d array and sometimes I will get an "error" and "message" back for that particular object. The problem I keep running into, Is that the messaging I am getting back varies...How do I go about if the "error" key is mentioned then delete the object entirely.

My Array:

```
let filtData = [
  [
    {
      descriptions: {
        attrs: {
          lang: "en-GB",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      descriptions: {
        attrs: {
          lang: "es",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      error: {},
      message: "Cannot read property 'attrs' of undefined"
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      descriptions: {
        attrs: {
          lang: "sp",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      descriptions: {
        attrs: {
          lang: "en-GB",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      descriptions: {
        attrs: {
          lang: "it",
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      descriptions: {
        attrs: {
          lang: "en",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      descriptions: {
        attrs: {
          lang: "uk",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      descriptions: {
        attrs: {
          lang: "en-GB",
        },
      },
    },
  ],
];
```

Js Filter - This only works when I know the messaging

```
let objectToBeRemove = [{ error: {}, message: "Cannot read property 'attrs' of undefined" }];
filtData = filtData.filter((obj) => objectToBeRemove.some((objToRemove) => JSON.stringify(objToRemove) !== JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `.every` of the elements in the subarray lack an `error` property.

```js
const input=[[{descriptions:{attrs:{lang:"en-GB"}}},{descriptions:{attrs:{lang:"es"}}},{error:{},message:"Cannot read property 'attrs' of undefined"}],[{descriptions:{attrs:{lang:"sp"}}},{descriptions:{attrs:{lang:"en-GB"}}},{descriptions:{attrs:{lang:"it"}}}],[{descriptions:{attrs:{lang:"en"}}},{descriptions:{attrs:{lang:"uk"}}},{descriptions:{attrs:{lang:"en-GB"}}}]];

const filtered = input.filter(
  subarr => subarr.every(obj => !obj.hasOwnProperty('error'))
);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: For some reason I keep getting the error - "subarr.every is not a function" anythoughts?

Comment: Works fine here, using the exact same input array in your question - press "Run code snippet" to see it working